# How to find multiple Regular Expression occurrences

Tags: regex

I have a text like **Here is the [mention name=Bugs Bunny id=1] and [mention name=Donald Duck id=2]**

What is the regex for capturing two different string?
1.[mention name=Bugs Bunny id=1]
2.[mention name=Donald Duck id=2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the *lazy* quantifier, to have a regex expression like:

```
/(\[.*?\])/g
```

You should use online regex builder, such as [regexr](https://regexr.com/) for example, to build and test your expressions.

Comment: The regex is **\[mention name=(.*?) id=(.*?)\]**. Thanks